# C# Datagridview: Ensure editing is done by hosted control only

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datetimepicker

I have a DataGridView with a DateTimePicker control hosted in one of the columns. Currently selecting a date assigns it to the value of the cell, but since I'm allowing the cell to be editable to utilize CellBeginEdit and CellEndEdit events, you can also type text into the column that may be invalid. How can I make it so editing the cell is enabled through the DateTimePicker only? See partial solution below:

```
DateTimePicker dtpVisit;


    private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        dtpVisit = new DateTimePicker();
        dtpVisit.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
        dtpVisit.Visible = false;
        dtpVisit.Width = 100;
        //DataGridView is called activities
        activities.Controls.Add(dtpVisit);

        dtpVisit.ValueChanged += this.dtpVisit_ValueChanged;
        ...
     }

private void activities_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if((activities.Focused) && (activities.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5))
            {
                dtpVisit.Location = activities.GetCellDisplayRectangle(e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex, false).Location;
                dtpVisit.Visible = true;
                dtpVisit.Focus();
                if (activities.CurrentCell.Value != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    dtpVisit.Value = (DateTime)activities.CurrentCell.Value;
                }
                else
                {
                    dtpVisit.Value = DateTime.Today;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    private void activities_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if((activities.Focused) && (activities.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 5))
            {
                activities.CurrentCell.Value = dtpVisit.Value.Date;
                dtpVisit.Visible = false;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void dtpVisit_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        activities.CurrentCell.Value = dtpVisit.Text;
    }

    private void activities_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
    {
        dtpVisit.Visible = false;
    }
```

Comment: I think you may want to check out MS article: [How to: Host Controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/how-to-host-controls-in-windows-forms-datagridview-cells) … the `DataGridView` control is a `CalendarColumn`. The cells in the column are `DateTimePicker`s. The article code is pretty much a copy/paste and would not only solve the problem, but would avoid laying the `DateTimePicker` on top of the grid and having to turn it on and off.

Comment: If you do not want to use the article, then you need to decide what “default” value you want when the user enters an invalid date. Wiring up the grids `CellValueChanged` event may be a good time to validate the date.

Comment: The Microsoft article really helped. Thank you